# How to prevent texture being override by blender

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking, remesh

I'm trying to baking a high poly texture to low poly model,and I found that somehow when baking blender always override the default image texture used by high poly model,sometimes explicitly clicks on the new texture image created the baking texture data will write to the new texture image,sometimes not it will just override the texture being used by high poly model.

to be clear,my workflow like this:

both blender 2.93 and blender 3 tested,using cycle to bake

## high poly model:

1. a 800000 faces model
2. a image texture named plane_basecolor.png(as the name showed it contains the base color data which can be used by PSDF)that already imported in to blender project.

## low poly model

1. a 20000 faces model created from high poly model and decimated,smart UV unwarpped.
2. a image texture named plane_bake.png was blank created by blender->UV editing->new image

follow the https://www.katsbits.com/codex/texture-bake/ guide here to do my bake,and when I finish the bake.I found the high poly model rending in viewport going wrong,check then found that baking result data didn't write to plane_bake.png but override into the plane_basecolor.png,makes the high poly model losing it's original texture,and the low poly didnt get the effective texture data.even I've already explicitly clicked the plane_bake.png in shading window before baking it still write to the plane_basecolor.png.

Is there any way to more explicitly tell blender to write the render result or baking result into the designated picture instead of default output(I'm not sure what this default render/baking output will go,sometimes it go plane_basecolor.png,sometimes go plane_bake.png or other texture),or is there any way to make designate textures in blender readonly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you selected the objects in the correct order? The *active* object is highlighted in orange. It's the target The *selected* one is highlighted in red (darker). It's the source.

Comment: The output is baked to whatever image is in the selected _Image Texture Node_ in the target object's material. Try putting your target image there. (You can use a floating Image Texture node that's not connected to anything.)

Comment: thanks for help,by checking with what  
Samuel Sullins I can confirm it's accidentally changed active image texture node when working and tab from different blender window.but I'm still wondering why not there gives a output filepath options in render->bake menu,since it's always easy to accidentally change window between UV,texture and render will mess up the current active image texture node